# I want a figure to be positioned above a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I have a picture which needs to be placed above another figure that I drew using tikzpicture. The pictures are being positioned side by side.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document} 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{m4.pdf}
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\node(A0) at (0,0) {p = 0};
\node(A1) at (10,0) {p = 1};

\path[->] (A0) edge node [below] {Increasing Ramdomness} (A1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

I want it to be like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You only need to put the picture in a node, `\node at (5,3) {\includegraphics[scale=1]{m4.pdf}};`. However, I do not have your picture, so I do not know if `(5,3)` works, you may need to use different coordinates.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I dunno, how would anyone benefit from this? It is, at least by some standards, a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/121799). And [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799) will always give you an idea which coordinates are to be used. (I would probably just draw these graphs with Ti*k*Z.)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Morally I agree but thanks to the tikz-pgf gold badge I can no longer just vote to close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: @marmot Close vote retracted since there's an answer

Answer (score 2):

Just load the optional `preview` package of the `standalone` class, and I quote (page 9):

> If enabled this option loads the `preview` package with the `tightpage`
>   option and wraps the content into a preview environment. This crops
>   the content to its natural size plus a specified border.

[image: exemple]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document} 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\node(A0) at (0,0) {p = 0};
\node(A1) at (10,0) {p = 1};

\path[->] (A0) edge node [below] {Increasing Ramdomness} (A1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `standalone` processes the content in *restricted horizontal mode* which means like inside `\hbox{..}` or `\mbox{..}`. This means there can't be line breaks like in paragraphs.
If you like to have line breaks / paragraphs you need to either provide the `varwidth` class option or the `preview` class option. The first uses a `varwidth` environment from the `varwidth` package around the content. The second switches the cropping code from `standalone`s own code to the `preview` package, which also allows paragraphs.

---

In this specific case you could also just place the `\includegraphics` inside a TikZ `\node` to place it as part of the picture on top of the other material.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like below.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
\node at (4,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}};
\node at (8,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}};
\node(A0) at (0,-2) {p = 0};
\node(A1) at (8,-2) {p = 1};
\path[->] (A0) edge node [below] {Increasing Ramdomness} (A1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, `Ramdomness` must be fixed to `Randomness`. However, it is left as it is for the sake of originality.